# Change Hamburger Menu Background in code or settings

Tags: c#, uwp, themes

Thanks in advance.

I've searched for a long time on net, nut haven't found anything. Please help and try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

In App.xaml, I have a ResourceDictionary like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="Backdrop" TintColor="White" TintOpacity=".6"/>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="White" TintOpacity=".8"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

In MicroSoft Navigation view website said:

[image]

It works, I change this color in ResourceDictionary, But I want to change this color in settings, I can't. I want to make user Customizing.

In code, I can't find Nav View's `NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground` or `NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground` property, just background property

[image]

I change this background, but it is NavPage's background Not change. and this place changed：

[image]

In code, I can't find Nav View's `NavigationView's background.

so, How do I do? How can I change this background in code?

[image]

or How do I write in ResourceDictionary or settings to make a theme system?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an `Acrylic Brush`, and set it to the `Background` property of your `NavigationView` object.

Checkout both Microsoft's documentation regarding [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) and [Acrylic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic)

Those two resources presented in `Generic.xaml`, are the default style implementation of the NavigationView object's `Background` for when the NavigationView is either in `Compact` or `Expanded` mode.

**Those are not dependency properties like the** `Background property`, **but rather** `resources`**which define acrylic brushes, which are set to the Background property of the NavigationView by default!, depending on its current visual state.**

If you want to define your own style, the easiest way is to re-use these two resources, since they already contain the UI logic for the transition between `Compact/Expanded` mode, that switches the Background from `In-App acrylic` to `Background acrylic`, and hence why the `BackgroundSource`property value is set to a different value on those 2 resources definition.

If you want to have the color of the Background Acrylic set to another color, you have to change the `TintColor` and `TintOpacity` dependency properties. In the resources defined above, the TintColor is set to `White`.

Like this,

```
<AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="Backdrop" TintColor="Blue" TintOpacity=".6"/>
<AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="Blue" TintOpacity=".8"/>
```

The `TintColor` dependency property is set to Blue for both background states: In-App and Background Acrylic, which should modify the color of the NavigationView's Pane.

If you want to enhance your Settings options, for your app to change between several states, you have to Bind the TintColor

Comment: I got it, thanks, but I don't know how to use bind in ResourceDictionary. such as I have a class named `NavStyle`, It have a object is color, how to use Bind with `TintColor`? I trid but not work :`TintColor="{x:Bind NavStyle.clolr}"`, can't find NavStyle class.

Comment: Now, In app.xaml.cs, I have a `public static Color color = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(System.Drawing.Color.Blue.A, System.Drawing.Color.Blue.R, System.Drawing.Color.Blue.G, System.Drawing.Color.Blue.B);`,  In AcrylicBrush: `<AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="Backdrop" TintColor="{Binding color}" TintOpacity=".6"/>`, it is not work, please help me ,thanks